# How can we create a drop-down menu to change the background theme of xy sci chart using html and js in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an XY sci chart in which I added two line charts with dummy data .Then I added a drop-down menu . **How can I add a drop-down menu to change the background theme of sci chart** using **html** **css** and **js** in *visual studio code*?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYFnH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atovb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMudn.png)

Comment: Do you have already some code?

Comment: Yes I will share